# Paramiko run script and exit

Tags: linux, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to make paramiko run a script on external machine and exit, but having problems to make it run the script. Do anyone know why its not running the script? I have tried to run the command manual on the VM and that worked.

```
command = "/home/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

def start_job(host):

    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        client.connect(hostname, port=22, username=username, password=password)
        return client.exec_command(command)

    finally:
        client.close()

start_job(hostname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's a typo in the `start_job` function on either the argument or the 1st param to `client.connect()`. Beyond that, just return the `stdout`/`stderr` contents before closing the connection:

```
def start_job(hostname):

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect(hostname, port=22, username=username, password=password)
    (_, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)
    return (stdout.read(), stderr.read())

finally:
    client.close()
```

In your case the command is redirecting stderr to stdout and running in background so I wouldn't expect nothing but two empty strings to be returned back:

```
start_job(hostname)
('', '')
```